# Convert String date to Java object with Timezone of client (without Locale)

Tags: java, date, timezone, jodatime

I need to create a 24hours window for a date passed by user to search result in database. The user could be in any TimeZone, the server is in PST and the database uses mongodb (UTC).

Looking for something like if user sends `Wed Dec 21 2016 00:07:11 GMT+0530 (IST)` then server creates a `new DateTime()` having same date and time (not gets converted by default to JVM's timezone)

One work around I thought of is to create a Date in user's Timezone withTimeAtStartOfDay and addDays plus 1 for window.

Eg: `String date = "Wed Dec 21 2016 00:07:11 GMT+0530 (IST)" convert to "2016-12-21 00:00:00.000Z"` NOTE : Server is in PST, so simple date object won't work.

How can I create a Date object in Java with Timezone of user (i.e String date user passes to BE).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the client's timezone in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1091372/5221149)

Comment: Your question is unclear.  The `Date` object doesn't carry a time zone, and the server's time zone is irrelevant to the problem at hand.  You don't say how you want to get the user's time zone, what the string containing the time zone might look like, or what kind of application you are working with.  It sounds like you might want a `ZonedDateTime` from the `java.time` APIs, but it's hard to say from what you've asked.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Comment: @Andreas - Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Carpet.  The OP did not ask about JavaScript.

Comment: @MattJohnson Before you can do anything relative to users timezone, you need to find what users timezone is. Hence, link to how to do that.

Comment: @MattJohnson I need to create a date object on server based on the String date passed by user (angular). The date `new Date()` will be in default running JVM timezone. Is it possible some how to create date object in java having same datetime as in client's machine.

Comment: The string produced by the JS `Date` object is not sufficient.  You need an IANA time zone identifier, such as `Asia/Kolkata`.  You should read [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22625076/634824) for how to go about this in JavaScript.  You can then use that identifier in your Java application.

Answer (score 1):

The server’s JVM’s current default time zone should be irrelevant to your programming. Always pass your desired/expected time zone in the optional arguments to various method calls. IMHO, those time zone arguments should be required rather than optional.

I do not know or use MongoDB, but [this page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#date) says you the native type for a date-time value is a a [64-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing) integer that represents the number of [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond) since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970) in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

A date-only value is ambiguous, having no real meaning without the context of a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. A few minutes after midnight is a new day in Paris France while still “yesterday” in Montréal Canada.

So if a time zone is required, where do we get one? Ultimately, the only safe sure way is to ask the user. Prompt the user for the [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

Without asking the user, you can only assume or guess. There are ways to detect via JavaScript the web-app client browser for its current default time zone. Discussed many times already on Stack Overflow, so search. But you do not know for sure that the browser zone is intended by the user making the query to you. You could assume a time zone or assume UTC, if your users are properly trained to work that way.

Locale has *nothing* to do with time zone, only presentation when generating a String representation. [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) determines (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, and such. You can have a `Asia/Kolkata` time zone with `Locale.CANADA_FRENCH` presentation, or a `Pacific/Auckland` time zone with a `Locale.ITALY` presentation. So, locale is irrelevant to this Question.

Use `LocalDate` for the date-only portion.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2016 , Month.MARCH , 23 );
```

Provide the time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
```

Get the start of day, the first moment. Let java.time determine this, as the first moment is *not* always the time-of-day `00:00:00`. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) may cause a different start time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ld.atStartOfDay( z );
```

We need a ending time for the search query. Usually in date-time handling we use the Half-Open approach where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So we want the query for a single day to run up to, but not include, the first moment of the *following* day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = ld.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z );  // Or, zdtStart.plusDays( 1 )
```

Apparently, MondoDB needs us to translate this to a count of milliseconds since the epoch in UTC. For that, extract an `Instant`.

```
Instant instantStart = zdtStart.toInstant();
Instant instantStop = zdtStop.toInstant();
```

From those, extract the epoch-count. This may mean data-loss! The java.time classes tracks values with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). Going to milliseconds may mean truncating a fine fraction of a second.

```
long millisStart = instantStart.toEpochMilli(); // WARNING: possible data loss.
long millisStop = instantStop.toEpochMilli(); // WARNING: possible data loss.
```

Comment: Looking for something like if user sends "Wed Dec 21 2016 00:07:11 GMT+0530 (IST)" then server creates a new DateTime() having same date and time (not get converts by default JVM timezone).

Comment: @nishi Post further information like this as edits to your Question rather than as Comments.